# pasting variables into a mutate_at function to mutate specific columns if they exist

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some data and I am trying to use `mutate_at` to mutate a few of the columns based on their column names.
However I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
> ```

How can I paste in some variables to `mutate_at`?

Libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Code:

```
vars_to_match <- c("Petal.Length_virginica", "Sepal.Length_virginica", "Sepal.Width_setosa")

my_Data %>% 
  mutate_at(
    .var = matches(paste(vars_to_match, collapse = "|")),
    .funs = c("Scale_Me")
  )
```

Data:

```
data(iris)
my_Data <- iris %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

Function:

```
Scale_Me <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)  # Standard Normal Distribution Function
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `vars()` which does the quoting, not `.vars`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

my_Data %>%
     mutate_at(
     vars(matches(paste(vars_to_match, collapse = "|"))),
     .funs = c("Scale_Me")
   )
```

which gives,

> ```
> A tibble: 150 x 13
>      row Sepal.Length_setosa Sepal.Length_versicolor Sepal.Length_virginica Sepal.Width_setosa Sepal.Width_versicolor Sepal.Width_virginica Petal.Length_setosa Petal.Length_versicolor Petal.Length_virginica Petal.Width_setosa Petal.Width_versicolor Petal.Width_virginica
>    <int>               <dbl>                   <dbl>                  <dbl>              <dbl>                  <dbl>                 <dbl>               <dbl>                   <dbl>                  <dbl>              <dbl>                  <dbl>                 <dbl>
>  1     1                 5.1                      NA                     NA             0.190                      NA                    NA                 1.4                      NA                     NA                0.2                     NA                    NA
>  2     2                 4.9                      NA                     NA            -1.13                       NA                    NA                 1.4                      NA                     NA                0.2                     NA                    NA
>  3     3                 4.7                      NA                     NA            -0.601                      NA                    NA                 1.3                      NA                     NA                0.2                     NA                    NA
> ```

Comment: maybe also recommend `list(Scale_Me)`?